# How is this capacitor connected between the inverting input and ground being used?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor

I found a schematic for a lithium polymer battery charging circuit where an op amp is used as a comparator. The battery voltage (adjusted by a pot on the left) is compared with a 3V reference provided by a zener diode. Can anyone tell why the 1 uF capacitor was included between the inverting input of the op amp and ground? Here's the schematic:

[image: charging circuit]

from https://www.homemade-circuits.com/usb-automatic-li-ion-battery-charger/

Comment: removes the "scratchiness" from the adjustment pot

Comment: It is a noise filter.  The circuit has no hysteresis, so this is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just stabilizing the voltage on the output of the voltage divider formed by the potentiometer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a not a great design and risks overtime above 3.8V which ought to only last 10% or so of a total charge.

Normally you have a predetermined charge current until 4.1 or so then when current drops below 5% of the CC rate at this CV threshold it cuts off and stays off unless restarted or some hysteresis threshold like 3.6 goes below and tops up the charge. This one will cycle on and off too quickly thus spending perhaps too much time.

Yet if the Zener is only 3V it won’t charge up at all.

The safe method is to use a 3.8V threshold as a float charge which takes longer but won’t overcharge it as much.

The basic theory is if the inverting input exceeds the +ve in
It threshold the output cuts off.  So anything more than 3.7 V will recycle and the higher towards 4.2V, the faster it will cycle as it slows sags down to 4V then 3.8 with a light load.

Yet as shown I suspect if it regulates to something like 3.7~3.8V , then it's ok.  If the Pot ratio is set to 3V/3.8V then it regulates at 3.8V

Comment: It's rather odd that the circuit doesn't actually measure the voltage across the battery directly.

Comment: That's normal. It uses the pot ratio to compare, but thanks for hinting at my oversight/