# Can we make a transformerless 220V to 12V converter without a Zener doide?

Tags: zener, transformerless

I saw many circuits have a Zener diode, but a guy from Youtube lighted up a 12V LED without a 12V Zener diode in the cicuit.

How is that?

[image]

Comment: 220V is lethal. Yes, we can build such a converter without a transformer, but it's **so dangerous** and usually **much more expensive than buying one that contains a transformer**  that we **simply do not do it**. The circuit you shown is terrible, **and should never be used**, especially not with R2=50Ω – are you trying to kill anyone? This simply explodes the moment you plug it in, if you have any bad luck.

Comment: also "that guy on youtube": Ah! obviously **that** guy on youtube! (nobody knows what you're referring to, so there isn't even a question here.)

Comment: also if the question is "what's an alternative to a zener diode for voltage regulation", then I recommend you search for "voltage regulator".

Comment: Sorry I'm all enraged, but where do people even dig up these circuits to make tutorials and youtube videos about them? These are death traps, and while there are some (fully enclosed, no touchable parts, very low current) application where this approach even remotely makes sense, proposing them as beginners project must have killed dozens of innocent people by now. It's irresponsible to start teaching power electronics by doing something as reckless as this!!

Comment: the video link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y74DUPU_8Nk

Comment: another one : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOu5qS-veBI

Comment: Oh, my, these are all **terrible**, especially for the purpose of powering an LED! Wah!!

Comment: Like, they don't even make sense: Cool, so you have a Zener diode in parallel with a high current LED of roughly the same forward voltage? The Zener does nothing! These guys understand *nothing* about what they're doing. Don't learn from Youtube videos. there's just too much sh*t out there.

Comment: @Marcus see also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/541804/how-is-this-capacitor-connected-between-the-inverting-input-and-ground-being-use and a bunch of others with the same watermark recently. I fear Electronics.SE may be turning into that website's technical support.

Comment: @BrianDrummond aw what  gaaawdaweful manure is that schematic even? The cherry on top of that pie is calling your websity "xyz innovation" when you're not even able to make a clean copy of a schematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to have a Zener diode in the circuit if you are powering LEDs.

A transformerless AC power supply without the Zener diode is a sort of really lame constant current source.

LEDs do best when powered from a constant current source.

You can approximate a constant current source by using a resistor in series with a voltage source.  The typical "DC voltage source and series resistor" circuit for driving LEDs is a sort of half-assed constant current source.

In your example circuit, C1 limits the current.  At 50Hz, it has an impedance of about 32 kilo ohms.  For 230VAC, that means a peak current of about 20 milliamperes.  No matter what, you can't draw more than about 20 milliamperes out of that circuit continuously.

If your LED can handle 20 milliamperes, then the voltage output of the circuit will drop to the forward voltage of the LED.  You don't have to regulate the voltage.  The current limit and the LED will take care of that.

The Zener diode turns the current source in a transformerless powersupply into a (near) constant voltage source.

Normally, you'd want that.  Microprocessors and other devices require a constant voltage, not a constant current.

---

Here is the circuit I traced out of a broken 230VAC LED light bulb:

[image]

It uses a transformerless power supply with no voltage regulation.  It depends on the input voltage being well regulated in order to provide a constant current to the LEDs.  It has no Zener to regulate the voltage.  The LEDs and the (near) constant current do that.

The AC power is mostly well behaved, but not always.  It gets spikes and noise and over voltage.

This circuit has next to no protection against over voltage, which is why it was broken.

At some point, it got a little too much voltage and allowed a little too much current to the LEDs.  That destroyed one LED, causing me to replace the bulb and have a look at the circuit.

---

As noted in the comments, you should avoid transformerless power supplies.

They are dangerous, and can potentially kill you if you touch any point inside of them - even the supposedly low voltage output.

If you build one, it should only be operated enclosed in an insulated housing.  It should not have any connections to anything outside the box except for the AC in.

All points in the circuit must be regarded as being at line voltage at all times.

Comment: How is the zener going to work (as a voltage regulator) without a resistor in series?

Comment: Can I use this circuit (if we don't bother the risk) for a 12V DC fan? Will that work since we need a constant voltage source in that case?

Comment: The resistor is there to reduce the current in a Zener regulated circuit.  The capacitor limits the current in a capacitive dropper.

Comment: This circuit is not the best  for a motor.  In truth, it is not a good circuit at all.

Comment: Which resistor, R1 or R2? or both? Sorry to ask again and again. I am noob at this.

Comment: Your diagram doesn't have a current limiting resistor in a place it would do any good with a Zener diode.  The resistors in the one I posted don't limit current, either.  They discharge the capacitors so that the bulb can't "bite" you when you take it out of the socket.

Comment: Seriously.  Don't build a capacitive dropper.

Comment: But then how will the zener work as a regulator without a series resistor?

Comment: The resistor is only there to limit the current.  What else limits the current?  In a capacitive dropper, the capacitor limits the current.

Answer (score 3):

**Do not build this circuit. Mains voltage is dangerous.**

**Circuits like this are only used inside an insulating plastic enclosure which must have no exposed parts or connections to external equipment.**

The answer is that yes you can make it without a Zener if the load is a 12V LED to begin with, but no you can't make if you have a variable load.

The rest of the circuit works identically, no matter which device will be the device that limits the voltage in it, a 12V Zener diode or a 12V LED.

If there is already a fixed load of 12V LED that limits the voltage, the Zener does almost nothing.

If you need a 12V supply that is not powering a fixed load, and must supply 12V regardless of load current, then you need the Zener for regulation, so that the voltage does not rise above 12V.

Comment: How this circuit is more dangerous than a transformer circuit?

Comment: Because it reads transformerless. This is not an isolated circuit. It is live with mains voltage. You should already be aware of how dangerous and lethal mains voltage circuits are before even thinking about building them.

Comment: @AbinLatheef:  Look at the diagram of the LED bulb I posted.  Follow the N(eutral) connection through to the LEDs.  There's nothing there but a diode - it's basically a straight  shot from N to the LEDs.  Now remember that L and N in an outlet can be swapped.  L is then straight through.  The LEDs are only exposed to the current through the capacitor.  If you touch the negative terminal of the LEDs, you will get nearly the full 230VAC applied to you.  Extreme ouch, or dead.

Comment: What if I use a voltage regulator with a full bridge rectifier? Even then the ground of the transistor will be 230V, right?